# Updating a Column with the minimum value of that same column depending on a 2nd column

Tags: mysql

Here is my table:

```
Col_1  | Col_2

1 | abcd  
2 | abcd  
3 | edcr  
4 | yhns  
5 | edcr
```

I would like to update Col_1 to return the following

```
Col_1  | Col_2

1 | abcd  
1 | abcd  
3 | edcr  
4 | yhns  
3 | edcr
```

I am trying to do this with `UPDATE` and `GROUP BY` but can't seem to be able to figure it out.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: It looks like you want ranking with ties (i.e. hence you've skipped 2) but then `yhns` would be 5 (because there are 2 edcr's at rank 3). Also, is the final order important?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
UPDATE table1 t1 JOIN table1 t2 ON t1.Col_2 = t2.Col_2 SET t1.Col_1 = t2.Col_1;
```

Note:  Make sure your Col_1 is not **Primary Key**

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee676/1)**

Comment: you are welcome. Also when you get what you want than accept that ans. so it become on the top and other can use it in future